# How to proxy pass from url path to different subdomain on different dns server?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, cloudflare

Let's say I have my main domain on one server and one of the subdomains to another server.

both of these addresses are using Cloudflare DNS to different ip addresses, so:

`example.com` => `ip1`

`new.example.com` => `ip2`

Now I want to proxy_pass a certain path on `example.com` to `new.example.com` without changing the url, so:

`example.com/something` should show content of `new.example.com/somethingElse`

These are my nginx config files, the problem is if I point `example.com/something` to google.com or even an `ngrok` server that I hosted for test, everything works just fine, but when I point it to `new.example.com/something` it gives me 502 error, so my guess is there's something wrong with my `new.example.com` config.

`example.com` Config:

```
server {

        listen 443 ssl http2;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

        ssl     on;
        ssl_certificate         /etc/letsencrypt/live/cert.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key     /etc/letsencrypt/live/key.pem;

        server_name example.com www.example.com;
        resolver 8.8.8.8;

        location = /something {
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host  new.example.com;
                proxy_set_header Host              new.example.com;
                proxy_pass https://new.example.com/somethingElse;
        }
}
```

`new.example.com` Config:

```
server {
  listen 443;

  server_name www.new.example.com new.example.com;

  ssl_certificate         /etc/ssl/private/cert.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key     /etc/ssl/private/key.pem;

  location / {
      proxy_pass         http://container-name:80;
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you try using CNAMEs in cloudflare? new.example.com pointing to example.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please test the connectivity between the servers. Login into example.com server and send CURL request to the new.example.com service.
Looks like example.com server is not able to reach new.example.com server.
Please check nginx service logs.

Another option to achieve your requirements is cloudflare worker service.